# Next.js useEffect block me to redirect to another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have page with all cards, if I click to specific card, it redirects me to this specific card. All is good. id is in url

```
http://localhost:3000/cards/card?id=6539ccd487fa315543646ce5
```

I grab this id and I found data in mongoDB and fetch this data.

```
const { id } = router.query


useEffect(() => {

    const fetchEventForEditting = async () => {

    try {
    
      const res = await axios.post('/api/card', {id } )
      setName(res.data.card.name)
      
    } catch (error) {       // pls read it all first,then it make sence
      console.log(error)   //  after pressing edit btn => here is error TypeError: 
                          // Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    }
     }

    fetchEventForEditting()
  }, [id])
```

data are fetch and inserted to card, all is good. I have btn in card for editing.
when I change data in form and click btn edit, data are changed in mongoDB.

Now is problem, It should redirect me, back to all cards page,
BUT it keeps me in this current page and show me error on useEffect -> fetchEventForEditting function on catch(...)
Next.js log me out,(I need to be log in when I want to see cards) and I am still on the same page.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
const editEvent = async () => {
  try {
    setLoad(true)

    const res = await axios.post('/api/cards/updateSingleEvent', data)
    console.log(res.data)
   
    setUpdatedImage('')
    router.push('/user/cardsDashboard')  // after changed data I should be redirected.

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } finally {
    setLoad(false)
  }
}
```

I try use rouder.push() or redirect method but I am not able to change current page.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it now. I added  e.preventDefault()

```
 const editEvent = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
```

and it is working.